# python imaplib raise socket error

Tags: python, imaplib

I want to retrive content from sent messages folder by the code below:

```
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.exmail.qq.com',993)
conn.login(user,pwd)
conn.select("Sent Messages")
mails = conn.search(None, 'ALL')

for num in mails[1][0].split():
    t, d = conn.fetch(num, 'RFC822')
if t == 'OK':
    print 'Message %s\n' % (num)
    msg = email.message_from_string(d[0][1])
    subject = email.Header.decode_header(msg['subject'])[0][0]

    if re.search(month, subject):
        print subject
else:
    print 'fetch error'
```

The `num` is between 1~36, when the `num` is 8. There comes an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "monthlySummary.py", line 30, in 
>       t, d = conn.fetch(num, 'RFC822')
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 455, in fetch
>       typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, message_set, message_parts)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 1087, in _simple_command
>       return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imaplib.py", line 911, in _command_complete
>       raise self.abort('command: %s => %s' % (name, val))
>   imaplib.abort: command: FETCH => socket error: unterminated line

I try to relogin, but still come the same error. what does this socket error mean? how can i solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the imaplib source code ([here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/Lib/imaplib.py)), the relevant function is:

```
def _get_line(self):
    line = self.readline()
    if not line:
        raise self.abort('socket error: EOF')

    # Protocol mandates all lines terminated by CRLF
    if not line.endswith(b'\r\n'):
        raise self.abort('socket error: unterminated line')

    line = line[:-2]
    if __debug__:
        if self.debug >= 4:
            self._mesg('< %r' % line)
        else:
            self._log('< %r' % line)
    return line
```

The comment in the function says that all lines must be terminated by CRLF, so it is obviously hitting a line that is not and so it aborts.

You need to make sure each line ends with `'\r\n'`, so to do that you could simply add this string to each line if it is not already there, before processing it. This will make sure that this error upon which the program is aborted is not raised.

Comment: Sorry， I can not understand what does the **line** mean in the source code? Could you give some hints? ;)

Comment: No problem. line is just that; a line from whatever file you are reading from. It is assigned to the result of the readline method, which is defined further up in the class, and is just a call to python's built-in readline method. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for more detail.